# How to model a table with a foreign key to a child entity in EF Core's Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

I am modifying the C# code generated by EF Core's scaffold command.  I rewrote the generated classes to reflect my business model.  My goal is to modify the Fluent API calls in the generated code to better match my business logic and table design.  I need help knowing which functions to call, and with what parameters.

I have several one-to-one relationships defined where the dependent entity is optional.  I do this by making an integer field in the principal table nullable; this field is the foreign key which points to a dependent record in another table.  The dependent doesn't know about the parent and that's okay because my business logic is fine without it.  I do not have a DbSet<> declared in the DbContect for the dependent entity.

In ALL of the documentation and tutorials I have found on-line in the last four days, the assumption is that my dependent table has a foreign key that points back to the principal, but this is just not the case.  I designed it this way so that it was easy to see by looking at the principal table that a dependent record was possible, but not required.  It's also easy to make the child required by making that int field non-nullable.

```
public class Business
{
  public int Id {get; private set;}
  public string BusinessName {get; set;}
  public string BusinessLicenseNumber {get; set;}
  public Address Address {get; set;} //Address CAN be null
}

public class Address
{
  public int Id {get; private set;}
  public string Line1 {get; set;}
  public string Line2 {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
  ...
}

Table Businesses
int Id Identity
varchar(50) BusinessName Non-Null
char(10) BusinessLicenseNumber Nullable
int AddressId Nullable // <<===!!

Table Addresses
int Id Identity
varchar (50) Line1 Non-Null
varchar (50) Line2 Nullable
varchar (50) City Nullable
...
```

If you could provide a URL, an example, or explanation of what I should do with this kind of one-to-one relationship, that would be great, because it doesn't match anything I've found so far, but I really like this kind of object and table model.

Comment: Your example doesn't show a one-to-one relationship.  A business can have one or more addresses so the relationship is still a one-to-many.  You should remove the AdressId column in the Business Table and add a foreign key in the Address table that references the Businesses.Id field for a proper DB design. Don't know if there is any use case for knowing if a business has an address or not in the business table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  As with many questions that go up on forums, I've simplified things.  My application doesn't really track businesses, but it does reflect what's going on in my model: a one-to-one relationship where the principal table has a foreign key to a dependent table.  It should be noted that the dependent table is used by other principal tables, so all objects of the same type are kept together.  I simply cannot link the dependent table back to all the principals because.  There is no need to traverse a dependent to get to a principal in my application.